# Set state_machine initial state conditional on other attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I have a Participant model, with state_machine last_action. I would like to set initial value of last_action depending on role attribute. If role is "Tutor", then initial value is "value 1", whereas if role is "Student" then initial value is "value 2".

How should I do this? (I am using state_machine gem in Rails 3.0).
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
before_validation :set_initial_last_action, :on => :create

state_machine :last_action do
  ...
end 

private

def set_initial_last_action
  if role == 'Tutor'
    self.last_action = 'value 1'
  elsif role == 'Student'
    self.last_action = 'value 2'
 end
end
```

Cheers